# Class Files not visible in Visual Studio 2011

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I ran Visual Studio 2012 today and tried to create a new solution with projects contained within.

The class source code for the boiler-plate Class1 file is not visible.  If I create a new class, the source code is also not visible.

When I click on a class file, the tab file opens with the class name but there is no source code.  Just a background color that was there before.  If I try to open any class file in notepad then the source code is visible.  The only thing I have done today is uninstall continuous tests after having a play with it.  This happens on any new project I create or with existing projects.

Has anyone seen this before and do you have a solution?  Ta very much.

*I cannot post images as I do not have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so problem solved. I had uninstalled Continuous Tests via the control panel and that was that. However, the plug-in was still visible from the Visual Studio add-in manager. I performed an uninstall from there and everything started working fine again. Source code is now visible. I can only put it down to the incorrect uninstall procedure. – DannyDuttser